# I can't install an addon

Tags: add-on

I tried installing [Blender MMD tools](https://github.com/sugiany/blender_mmd_tools) both by using install from file and the zip, and by adding it to the addons folder. It still does not appear in the list of addons. Does that addon not work with the current version of blender? Is there something else?

Is there any simple blender addon I could try to see if I have problems installing addons in general?

Comment: this is a very common issue @DanielLC , it's something that could easily be addressed in Blender's 'install from zip' feature by developers -- until then you could extract the `mmd_tools` folder from the zip, then zip the folder as `mmd_tools.zip`, that will install just fine.